# pass as parameter tcpdump output

Tags: bash, tcpdump

I want to execute something like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -n dst port 40010 -X
```

pass each packet received to bash file read.sh

and foreach packet received execute read.sh

It's like

```
sudo bash read.sh -y (tcpdump -n dst port 40010 -X)
```

Or

```
tcpdump -n dst port 40010 -X > read.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to pass output from one command to another is a pipeline.

```
tcpdump | script
```

However, this will cause `script` to receive a continuous stream of output, one line at a time.  The output from `tcpdump` splits one packet over several lines, so if `script` assumes it will receive a single packet, you will need to parse the output somehow.

Based on brief experimentation, something like the following should work:

```
tcpdump -n dst port 40010 -X |
awk '/^[0-9]/ && $2 != "packets" {
        if (p) { print p | "script"; close("script"); } p=$0 }
    /^[ \t]/ { p=p "\n" $0 }
    END { if(p) print p | "script" }'
```

An additional quirk is that pressing ctrl-C will terminate the whole pipeline, so you will lose the last few packets completely.  I avoided this by specifying a number of packets with `-c` but you could also protect the Awk script by running it with a `trap` to block signals.  However, at this point, I would perhaps consider switching to Python or something.  Of course, incorporating the packet splitting into `script` itself would also help.

Comment: the command stop at 20-24 packets itself... Where is storaged the packet in "script"?

Comment: It is read from standard input, one packet at a time.  What happens inside `script` is up to you, really.